# If statement to make a button appear/disappear based on the results of game

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have 1v1 browser games on my website & I'm trying to make a button show up for the winner & not show up for the loser on a pop-up modal in the post-game. I'm specifically targeting the "Claim Prize" button on the pop-up" [Pop-up Modal "Claim Prize"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6xXi.png)

HTML for the Button:

```
  <button class="button button--secondary button--small modal__button"
  data-button="claim">
  Claim Prize
</button>
```

Js used to define the winner.

```
function endGame() {
  if(!isGameOver) return;
  let text;
  if(scores.player > scores.opponent) 
    text = TEXTS.win;
  else if(scores.player < scores.opponent)
    text = TEXTS.lose;
  else
    text = TEXTS.draw;
  
  text += `<br> Scores: ${scores.player} - ${scores.opponent}`;

  showEndScreen(text);
```

Current if statement to attempt to make it show only for the winner:

```
<script>
  var theyLost = (TEXTS.Win)
  if (theyLost) true;
  document.getElementById("claim").style.display="none";
</script>
```

Comment: The current script is run when the page loads, at that time you most likely don't know the winner? Also, `if (theyLost) true;` does nothing, maybe you meant: `if (theyLost === true) {document.getElem ...;}`?

Comment: it is recommended to use 'const' or 'let' instead of 'var', and the if statement should be written in below format: 
```
let theyLost = (TEXTS.Win) 
if (theyLost) {
    document.getElementById("claim").style.display="none"; 
}
```

Comment: Hey! thank you guys for the suggestions, I'll try implementing them now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but perhaps you can try directly making the button visible if the player wins:

```js
function endGame() {
  if(!isGameOver) return;
  let text;
  if(scores.player > scores.opponent){
    text = TEXTS.win;
    document.getElementById("claim").style.display="none";
  }else if(scores.player < scores.opponent){
    text = TEXTS.lose;
  }else{
    text = TEXTS.draw;
  }
  text += `<br> Scores: ${scores.player} - ${scores.opponent}`;

  showEndScreen(text);
}
```

Comment: Hey, any suggestion is great! I'll test it out right now!

Comment: I just tried it out, definitely a step in the right direction however, I'll need to refine this a bit further. Thank you so much for the help thus far!